# How do I SQL Query MinIO objects using the MinIO Client (mc)?

Tags: minio

Getting into Minio. Investigating a few commands,

If I do `mc ls alias/bucket` then I get expected output:

```
[2020-12-09 19:48:15 UTC]    10B Account-9.dta
[2020-12-09 19:48:22 UTC]    10B Account-90.dta
[2020-12-09 19:48:22 UTC]    11B Account-92.dta
```

So, I would expect some kind of output when I execute the following on the same connection:

`mc sql --recursive --query "select * from s3object" alias/bucket`

but instead, it just goes back to a prompt (No results).  I suspect my "from" is wrong but I have no idea what values to use other than "s3object".

How do I properly perform SQL queries on a local MinIO instance?

**MinIO Version:**

VERSION
2019-08-14T20:37:41Z
MEMORY
Used: 4.4 MB | Allocated: 3.6 GB | Used-Heap: 4.4 MB | Allocated-Heap: 65 MB
PLATFORM
Host: minio-66c9cd74c9-7m6lx | OS: linux | Arch: amd64
RUNTIME
Version: go1.12.8 | CPUs: 12

**MinIO Client Version:**

mc version RELEASE.2020-11-25T23-04-07Z

Answer (score 0):

When you specify multiple objects, mc filters objects by extension.

If you store files with a `.csv` extension they should be picked up. Similar for `.json` files and gzip/bzip2.